# UIDocumentInteractionController preview .ics in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6

iOS6 and xcode 5.01;

When i run with iphone simulator, it can preview the file, but with device, it failed.

```
//device path
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Applications/1AE864F5-A57F-47E7-829E-69DCFC63D8CD/tmp/11523invite.ics";
UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO]];
controller.delegate =self;
[controller presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

What's happend?

Comment: Device path is static or generate at run time?? "/var/mobile/Applications/1AE864F5-A57F-47E7-829E-69DCFC63D8CD/tmp/11523invite.ics".

Comment: @PiyushDubey Generated at rum time.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
```

use property of UIDocumentInteractionController